# Google API PHONETIC keyboard doesn't work in chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-api

`<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.google.com/jsapi">` doesn't work in chrome extension. Actually I was trying to use Google API for PHONETIC keyboard
like this

```
google.load("elements", "1", {packages: "keyboard"});

function onLoad() {
google.elements.keyboard.enableKeyCodeScheme(false);
new google.elements.keyboard.Keyboard(
  [google.elements.keyboard.LayoutCode.MALAYALAM_PHONETIC],
  ['t']);
document.getElementById('t').focus();
} 
google.setOnLoadCallback(onLoad);
```

**manifest.json** permission seem to be fine:-
`"permissions": ["tabs","http://*/*","https://*/*"],`

still console appearing like this [image]

Answer (score 0):

Have a read about the [Content Security Policy](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contentSecurityPolicy) for extensions.

More specifically, you cannot normally [load external scripts](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contentSecurityPolicy#resourceLoading).

However, as long as the script origin is `https`, you can [relax the default CSP](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contentSecurityPolicy#relaxing-remote-script) by adding the following in the manifest:

```
"content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' https://www.google.com; object-src 'self'"
```

Be sure to change your script tag link to https.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, with that change I am getting another error in console **Uncaught ReferenceError: google is not defined**. the error mentioned here `google.load("elements", "1", {packages: "keyboard"});`